# Communication between Cordova and Android Native App

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a Cordova application that needs to communicate with a native android app. It basically needs to send a message to the native android app to do something and then get a response back. So far, I have looked at using Cordova plugins, and I can't find any plugin that can help with this. I will appreciate any pointer in the right direction. I believe that I may need to implement a custom plugin for this.

Comment: Where are both apps running?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use URLs/universal links, custom schemes.

There are also intents.